# The remote name could not be resolved on Server fine in VS

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

I use this code to send an email from my webapp:

```
            SmtpClient s = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

            s.EnableSsl = true;
            s.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            NetworkCredential myCreds = new NetworkCredential("xxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxx");

            s.Credentials = myCreds;

            s.Send(m);
```

Testing this on my machine it runs fine but it stop working on my server. It was working fine for 6 months. The server is on the same network as my machine and they share the same public IP.